Numbering system of equations and specific lines therein
Suppose I want to write an optimization problem like in the following picture: 
From ChatGPT, the Latex is:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & f(\mathbf{x}) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & h_i(\mathbf{x}) = 0, \quad i = 1, 2, \dots, m \\
& g_j(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0, \quad j = 1, 2, \dots, p \\
& \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{S}.
\end{align*}


But now I want to put a label on the entire problem AND separate labels on each line (or at least some lines). That way I will be able to refer to problem (e.g. 1) as well as lines (2, 3, 4, or 1.a, 1.b, 1.c etc.).
What is the best way to do this? From another answer, I see that Subequations may be useful for this. Is that the best way or is there another approach?
Thank you.


I see that subequations may be useful for this. Is that the best way or is there another approach?


It's the best approach if you want the four rows to be numbered 1a thru 1d. Do note that you'll also need to switch from an align* environment to an align environment.
If you'd rather have the four rows be numbered 1 thru 4, all you'll need to do is replace both instances of align* with align.

If you select the former approach, you can create a cross-reference to the entire group of equations by inserting a suitable \label directive immediately after \begin{subequations}, but before \begin{align}.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' and 'subequations' environments
\usepackage{newtx} % optional: Times Roman text and math fonts
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{eq:overall}
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} \quad & f(\mathbf{x}) \label{eq:min}\\
\text{subject to} \quad & h_i(\mathbf{x}) = 0, \quad i=1,2,\dots,m \label{eq:h}\\
& g_j(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0, \quad j = 1,2,\dots,p \label{eq:g}\\
& \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{S}. \label{eq:cal-S}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

A cross-reference to the collection of equations: \eqref{eq:overall}. 

Cross-references to individual equations: \eqref{eq:min}, \eqref{eq:h}, \eqref{eq:g}, and \eqref{eq:cal-S}.
\end{document}


He also wanted to label the whole problem (not sure where and how though)

Yes thanks, I was hoping there could be a label, say (1), to the right of the 1a,...,1d labels and vertically centered. Then I could refer to problem 1 as well as constraint 1c and stuff.

@Smithey What further information would that label carry?

@egreg The idea would be to reference the whole problem rather than a specific line. Alternatively, I could just refer to the first line which contains the objective. Perhaps that's the standard practice?

Ok solution: Putting a label inside the subequation but outside the align does the trick as far as reference. I guess I don't need the number 1 to appear in the equation addition to the 1a 1b etc, as long as I can reference the 1. So all good now.

@Smithey - I've augmented the LaTeX code in the answer to address your question about creating a cross-reference to the entire group of equations (when using the subequations approach).
